# Repeatedly select in ‘random’ order the components of three sets of ten each

Tags: excel, random, probability

I wish to assign randomly (sort of) the numbers `1`, `2` and `3` to 30 rows such that every time I run the randomization I get ten instances of each number.

I do know of [=RANDBETWEEN](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/randbetween-HP005209230.aspx) but am not sure how to ensure each of the three numbers is output with equal probability, but in a varying sequence.

Is there a convenient [software algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for this, using Excel functions?

Comment: I have never done that before. What about you? Have you tried doing so?

Comment: I disagree that this is off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is called a shuffle - randomly ordering a fixed set of elements.

Fill the array with 10 1's, 10 2's, and 10 3's, then run a random shuffle on it.

You should be able to find descriptions on shuffle algorithms with a web search.